# java : A fatal error is coming while runnig Swing Application(.6.0_18-b07)

Tags: java

Below added fatal error log. `-Dsun.java2d.d3d=false`(work around) added to classpath . Still fatal error coming. can any one help on this issue?

```
java : A fatal error is coming while runnig Swing Application(.6.0_18-b07). 

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6d1668b0, pid=8116, tid=7428
   JRE version: 6.0_18-b07
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (16.0-b13 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
 Problematic frame:
C  [awt.dll+0xb68b0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general hint with this type of error: search for `[awt.dll+0xb68b0]` -- or the equivalent with other problems. [This is the top result](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=d6f0ced1aee943ffffffffbe49e2bee033da9?bug_id=6961986), there's a workaround at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a JVM bug - it means that Java itself crashed (not your application).

Asides from upgrading your JRE and hoping the issue is fixed, there's not much you can do.  (Unless you can reproduce this reliably and feel you have data to contribute to the bug report.)